# How to verify empty input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am programming in `php` and my `sql` I have a form with personal data and a `submit` save button . So I want to validate that `input` the person's root is not empty, and therefore do not let save.

I have this function `js`:

```
function validate(){
    if ($('#txtrut').text() == "") {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

I execute it in the onclick event of the submit, but it always shows me the alert, it is empty the input or not. How can I do it?

Comment: It should be `.val()`, not `.text()`.

Comment: Can the php tag be safely removed? This doesn't seem php related, or... is it? You do know that client side checking isn't the best and a server side method should (also) be used.

Comment: `trim()` is also a good idea.

Comment: Copied without attribution from [Comprobar input vacio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/16436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `val()` not `text()`. However, to be absolutely certain and to perform a more coherent check, you should use the `length` of the value as the conditional.

```
function validate(){
    if (!$('#txtrut').val().length) {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

**Note:** Keep in mind this verification will still accept blank spaces. To avoid that to some extent you can use the `trim` method.

```
function validate(){
    if (!$('#txtrut').val().trim().length) {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate(){
    if ($('#txtrut').val() == "") {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

and for javascript

```
function validate(){
    if (document.getElementById("txtrut").value == "") {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user the event preventDefault() with jquery to block the submission event

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e){
          if ($('#txtrut').val() == "") {
            alert('Ingrese rut');
            e.preventDefault(e);
         }
        });
    });
    </script>
```